# Plot3D: why certain part of the plot is excluded?

Tags: plotting

Here is a simple 3D plot, but some part of the plot is excluded.

```
wq[k_, xe_] := Max[ 90 xe - k, -5] 
Plot3D[ wq[k, xe] , {k, 0, 50}, {xe, 0, 0.5}]
Plot3D[ wq[k, xe] , {k, 0, 50}, {xe, 0, 0.5}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Although I can fix the problem by using Exclusions->None, I am still puzzled by why there is such a large gap in the original plot.  In fact, my original plot range was very small, and the entire surface was excluded-- I got an empty plot.  I spent hours looking for errors and finally realized that I was plotting an excluded area.  Could any expert explain how exclusion area is determined in Mathematica?  Why such a large area is excluded in such a simple plot?  Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: no such problem in V 12 in windows 10. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gAfCe.png)

Comment: This is strange. When I run it again, now the gap shows up! May be it was a chance first time it worked. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws8ch.png). But if you add `Exclusions -> "Singularities"` to first plot, then it becomes OK. Look at help for `Exclusions`